# Single Object Realm Change Listener

Tags: android, realm

```kotlin
open class Person(
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: Long,
    var name: String,
    lateinit var dog: Dog
): RealmObject()
```

I know you can add `addChangeListener` to `RealmResults` but how to do it with a single object like this `realm.where(Person::class.java).findFirst()`?

based on the model above, I want to be notified if any of `Dog` data is updated so I can update the UI. how can I achieve this?